# Ruby gsub group parameters do not work when preceded by escaped slashes

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to perform a trivial substitution, that in any other language I have come across, work as per the documentation.  However, my substitution fails for some reason.  The documentation examples list:

```
"hello".gsub(/[aeiou]/, '*')                  #=> "h*ll*"
"hello".gsub(/([aeiou])/, '<\1>')             #=> "h<e>ll<o>"
"hello".gsub(/./) {|s| s.ord.to_s + ' '}      #=> "104 101 108 108 111 "
"hello".gsub(/(?<foo>[aeiou])/, '{\k<foo>}')  #=> "h{e}ll{o}"
'hello'.gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => 3, 'o' => '*')    #=> "h3ll*"
```

I am using the second form, to match `[` and `]` characters in a string and escape them  The regular expression is working correctly, but the substitution is not:

```
print "example[1][2].dat".gsub(/(\[|\])/, "[\\\1]")
```

The resultant output is:

```
$ ruby -e 'print "example[1][2].dat\n".gsub(/(\[|\])/, "[\\\1]")'
example[\]1[\][\]2[\].dat
```

The correct output should be as demonstrated by Python:

```
$ python -c 'import re ; print re.sub(r"(\[|\])", r"[\\\1]", "example[1][2].dat")'
example[\[]1[\]][\[]2[\]].dat
```

And even Perl handles it with grace:

```
$ perl -pe <<<"example[1][2].dat" 's/(\[|\])/[\\\1]/g
example[\[]1[\]][\[]2[\]].dat
```

I am guessing it is because the slashes are not being treated in raw form in the Ruby implementation, but in Python, that's easily solved by prefixing the strings with `r` - `r"[\\\1]"`.  Playing further, it seems Ruby doesn't cope well being passed strings on the command line, with double escaping everything, in order to be able to pass single quotes to Ruby's interpreter:

```
$ ruby -e 'print "example[1][2].dat\n".gsub(/(\[|\])/, '"'"'[\1]'"'"')'
```

To simplify, I placed all that in a small script instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
print "example[1][2].dat\n".gsub(/(\[|\])/, '[\1]')
```

Now the result at least yields the group parameter:

```
$ /tmp/re.rb
example[[]1[]][[]2[]].dat
```

But with the slashes it fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
print "example[1][2].dat\n".gsub(/(\[|\])/, '[\\\1]')
```

And run it...

```
$ /tmp/re.rb
example[\1]1[\1][\1]2[\1].dat
```

So I tried another solution from the documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
print "example[1][2].dat\n".gsub(/(\[|\])/, { ']' => '[\\]]', '[' => '[\\[]' })
```

Which actually seems to work:

```
$ /tmp/re.rb
example[\[]1[\]][\[]2[\]].dat
```

Which is now identical to the python implementation:

```
$ python -c 'import re ; print re.sub(r"(\[|\])", r"[\\\1]", "example[1][2].dat")'
example[\[]1[\]][\[]2[\]].dat
```

**Question**

Is there an easier way to accomplish this without needing to elaborate on each character I already matched in the expression?

Comment: Please make the question concise and remove subjective expressions.

Comment: You mean, sound like a robot?

Comment: Affirmative, subjective expressions removed.  Roger roger.

Comment: I agree , please make your question concise

Comment: Please refrain from comments such as "Ruby doesn't cope well", especially since this doesn't even have anything to do with Ruby. Shell escaping is done by, well, the shell, there's absolutely nothing Ruby can do about you choosing to use a shell in which `'` and `"` have a special meaning.

Comment: That's not correct.  The escaping is done from within a script and still doesn't produce the correct behaviour.  The reason was pointed out in the accepted answer.  So, Ruby does behave differently and in "my own" opinion, it's not intuitive if you consider other languages don't behave like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write a python code using ruby syntax. This is not a best approach to GTD.

Slashes are handled right-to-left, yielding not what you expected. As soon as one finds herself putting three or more backslashes inside the string, she should admit, she’s doing it wrong. At least for the sake of future code supporters. Below is a version, having no glitches:

```
"example[1][2].dat".gsub(/\[|\]/) { |m| "[\\#{m}]" }
#⇒ example[\[]1[\]][\[]2[\]].dat
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/fpm-1.3.3/lib/fpm/package/rpm.rb:167: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
10:19:15     name = name.gsub(/\[|\]|\*|\?|\%/, {|m| "[\\#{m}]"})`

Comment: Blocks are not passed to functions as regular parameters, you have an extra comma between formal parameter (regexp) and code block.